# React Native: render string as javascript code inside <Text></Text> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react native app I render a faq screen with a list I populate from a Json file and render inside a FlatList, in some of the strings there are links or call to actions  which look like this:

```
"Estan quebrantando las <Text onPress={ ()=>{ root.mapStore.openUrl('https://page.com/privacy-policy') } } style={{ color:'#F37F06' }}>Reglas de la comunidad</Text> o <Text onPress={ ()=>{ root.mapStore.openUrl('https://page.com/privacy-policy') } } style={{ color:'#F37F06' }}>Términos y condiciones</Text>"
```

How can I properly render the string as an inline Text component:

```
<Text>{ jsonBody }</Text>
```

Comment: You don't. Unless you're gonna write a custom templating engine to parse the json and turn it into JSX elements. Which is probably not gonna happen. It's probably a better idea to normalize your data (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) so your frontend doesn't have to jump through a 1000 hoops.

Answer (score 0):

you can use json as

```
    {
      "faq":[
        {"text":"some text", "script":"some script", "link": "some link"},
        {"text":"some text", "script":"some script", "link": null},
        {"text":"some text", null, "link": "some link"},
      ]
   }
```

and treat text, script, link as they are needed

> as there is no complete information in question of what the json looks like and what exactly you want to do with that script, treat as `code` or `string`, cant provide enough sufficient solution